# Time out error during Deployment in Binance Smart Chain

Tags: blockchain, solidity, truffle, binance

I got an error while deploying contract in Binance Smart Chain

plz help me if anybody knows it

error message looks like this

```
   Deploying 'WhitePaperInterestRateModel'
   ---------------------------------------
   > transaction hash:    0xa24026a456f81238422b262cc49bcb9ee494997b70ea8d41c092710f98b27d50
   ⠧ Blocks: 23           Seconds: 69Error [ERR_UNHANDLED_ERROR]: Unhandled error. ({
  code: -32603,
  message: 'ETIMEDOUT',
  data: { originalError: { code: 'ETIMEDOUT', connect: true } },
  stack: 'Error: ETIMEDOUT\n' +
    '    at Timeout.<anonymous> (/Users/hyunki/Desktop/compound/compound_test/truffle-compound-bsc/venus-protocol/node_modules/request/request.js:848:19)\n' +
    '    at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:556:17)\n' +
    '    at processTimers (node:internal/timers:499:7)'
})
    at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:329:5)
    at Web3ProviderEngine.emit (node:events:368:17)
    at /Users/hyunki/Desktop/compound/compound_test/truffle-compound-bsc/venus-protocol/node_modules/@trufflesuite/web3-provider-engine/index.js:57:14
    at afterRequest (/Users/hyunki/Desktop/compound/compound_test/truffle-compound-bsc/venus-protocol/node_modules/@trufflesuite/web3-provider-engine/index.js:151:21)
    at /Users/hyunki/Desktop/compound/compound_test/truffle-compound-bsc/venus-protocol/node_modules/@trufflesuite/web3-provider-engine/index.js:176:21
    at /Users/hyunki/Desktop/compound/compound_test/truffle-compound-bsc/venus-protocol/node_modules/@trufflesuite/web3-provider-engine/index.js:238:9
    at /Users/hyunki/Desktop/compound/compound_test/truffle-compound-bsc/venus-protocol/node_modules/async/internal/once.js:12:16
    at replenish (/Users/hyunki/Desktop/compound/compound_test/truffle-compound-bsc/venus-protocol/node_modules/async/internal/eachOfLimit.js:61:25)
    at /Users/hyunki/Desktop/compound/compound_test/truffle-compound-bsc/venus-protocol/node_modules/async/internal/eachOfLimit.js:71:9
    at eachLimit (/Users/hyunki/Desktop/compound/compound_test/truffle-compound-bsc/venus-protocol/node_modules/async/eachLimit.js:43:36)
    at /Users/hyunki/Desktop/compound/compound_test/truffle-compound-bsc/venus-protocol/node_modules/async/internal/doLimit.js:9:16
    at end (/Users/hyunki/Desktop/compound/compound_test/truffle-compound-bsc/venus-protocol/node_modules/@trufflesuite/web3-provider-engine/index.js:217:5)
    at Request._callback (/Users/hyunki/Desktop/compound/compound_test/truffle-compound-bsc/venus-protocol/node_modules/@trufflesuite/web3-provider-engine/subproviders/rpc.js:36:21)
    at self.callback (/Users/hyunki/Desktop/compound/compound_test/truffle-compound-bsc/venus-protocol/node_modules/request/request.js:185:22)
    at Request.emit (node:events:379:20)
    at Timeout.<anonymous> (/Users/hyunki/Desktop/compound/compound_test/truffle-compound-bsc/venus-protocol/node_modules/request/request.js:851:16)
    at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:556:17)
    at processTimers (node:internal/timers:499:7)
```

truffle-config.js

```
    testnet: {
      provider: () => new HDWalletProvider(mnemonic, `https://data-seed-prebsc-1-s2.binance.org:8545/`),
      network_id: 97,
      gas: 20000000,        // Ropsten has a lower block limit than mainnet
      gasPrice: 20000000000,  // 20 gwei (in wei) (default: 100 gwei)
      confirmations: 1,
      timeoutBlocks: 50000,
      skipDryRun: true
    },
```

I got endpoint at the page below

https://docs.binance.org/smart-chain/developer/rpc.html

Comment: I'm experiencing this all the time now too.

Comment: same issue here any solution found ?

Comment: some issue. Also getting sometimes "bad gateway"

Answer (score 0):

I use to have same issue, after switch to other network connection it's work fine. The course of the problem could possibility from the unstable connection.